# python project is not running in visual studio

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I am new to Django and Python. I made this simple [project](https://github.com/dharmendrak603/myfirstproject) and it was running properly earlier, so I moved out to some other project.

However now when I run this project, it gives me error below. Actually I don't remember the virtual enviroment name, but I remember that it should be one of denvx or 111.

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 
>   Requested setting DEBUG, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.`

Comment: can you show the terminal commands please?

Comment: @COB i simply want to run the localhost server see below----                           django-admin runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\kumardha\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\kumardha\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\kumardha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\django-admin.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>

Comment: @COB    File "c:\users\kumardha\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "c:\users\kumardha\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "c:\users\kumardha\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)

Comment: @COB  File "c:\users\kumardha\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 60, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "c:\users\kumardha\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "c:\users\kumardha\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 67, in handle
    if not settings.DEBUG and not settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS:

Comment: @COB  File "c:\users\kumardha\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 76, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "c:\users\kumardha\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 57, in _setup
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEBUG, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

Answer (score 0):

apologies, i was doing it wrong way. my command wasn't correct. it started working now... thanks